# Nullable specifier syntax

Tags: objective-c

I've got a property. The declaration is as follows:

```
 @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* inputRoute;
```

The compiler is whining at me about the lack of a nullability specifier which I have used elsewhere. My original attempt was

```
 @property (nonatomic, copy) nullable NSString* inputRoute;
```

which matches the syntax used for method arguments. Unfortunately, the compiler gave a syntax error. I subsequently moved it forward one token at a time until it was right at the end and the compiler always threw a syntax error.

Where are you supposed to put this to make the compiler shut up?

Comment: It is all a deep plan by the illuminati (read CL) to make Objective-C ugly and hard to use so we will move to Swift. Making us write `nonatomic` all the time was not enough, now it is `nonatomic, nullable`. See, they can't make Swift easier so this is the only option they have left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@property (nonatomic, copy, nullable) NSString *string1;
@property (nonatomic, copy, nonnull) NSString *string2;
```

See [Nullability and Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID45) in **Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C (Swift 2)**